# Bidirectitional Mapping throws stackoverflow exception, when Entity is resaved with same id

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Example, I have an entity named MaterialMaster, and I have an extension named ExtensionOne with the code as follows:

```
@Entity
public class MaterialMaster {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "extensionOne.materialMaster", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<ExtensionOne> extensionOneList = new ArrayList<>();
    
}
```

Extension One:

```
@Entity
public class ExtensionOne {
    @Embeddable
    public static class ExtensionOneId implements Serializable {
          @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
          @JoinColumn(name = "material_id")
          @JsonIgnore
          private MaterialMaster materialMaster;

          @Column(name = "extension_one_id")
          private Long extensionOneId;
    } 
    @EmbeddedId
    private ExtensionOneId id;

    private String description;

    // Other attributes, getters, setters
}
```

I have a dto corressponding to materialMaster, and I have a service class which takes the materialMasterDto and saves it.

```
    public void saveMaterialMaster(MaterialMasterDTO materialMasterDTO) {
        MaterialMaster materialMaster = materialMasterDTOConverter.convertToEntity(materialMasterDTO);
        materialMasterRepository.save(materialMaster);
    }
```

**Note:** Instead of creating the materialMaster first and then saving the extensions, I am converting the dto to the materialMasterEntity by appending the extensions to the extensionList present in materialMaster and saving it as a whole. (I don't know if this is the correct way to do this)

**Issue:**
When I first try to save the materialMasterData, it gets saved perfectly. But let's say if I again pass the materialMasterData with the same id, with the intent to overrride it not update it, it throws me the following exception:

StackOverflow Exception.

**MySolution:**
To avoid this what I have done is, first I findBy materialMaster and if it is present, I delete it first and then save it using @Transactional to my saveMethod.

I feel like this is not the correct way to do it.

I would like to know what exactly is causing the stackoverflow exception and how to avoid it and why isn't it being caused during the first time I save it and if the stackoverflow exception is caused by bidirectional mapping, how can I avoid it while saving it?

**Exception**
[image: Added exception for detial]

Comment: Can you show us the exception or at least part of the exception (because it will probably contain a lot of repetitions due to the stack overflow)?

Comment: Hi I have added the exception that it throws

Comment: Is there a repeating or circular stack in there? The error shows class loading, so it is unlikely to do with the bidirectional relationship, but doesn't hint at the problem with anything you've shown - your application might just need to run with a larger stack memory setting (-Xss).